# OpenGLES 2.0 app not working on tablet while working on smartphones - Black screen

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, tablet

I have developped a small openGLES2.0 app which is compatible from android version 8 to 17.
It basically renders a sphere model with simple texturing in an empty scene. I also keep track of device sensors like accelerometer. All is working fine and cool on a wide variety of android phones (GS2, GS3, GN2, Nexus...).

My simple problem is that i can't get it working on tablets (GT2 running on 4.1.1 for example). The app is installed correctly, it doesn't crash at all, i just see a black screen instead of my sphere model. The part of the application that doesn't use openGL is running perfectly.

I can't believe that OpenGLES 2.0 is not working on GT2, neither sensors, neither internet connection that i used also. Is there something to check/enable to get it working ? Maybe something related to the larger size of screen on tablets ? I could maybe post a bit of code but i think the problem is elsewhere...

Thanks for your time !

Comment: It seems that i get wrong with default orientation mode : I fixed it to portrait but on tablet, it is often inverted. So i have to compensate it with different angles to have the scene correctly displayed.

Comment: After further investigations, the project is running on Google Nexus 10 tablet without any problem. Maybe certain Open Gl calls are not available on Galaxy tab 2 then...

Answer (score 0):

When you use GLES 2.0 on devices you must be careful with indices. On many devices you cannot use `int` index. Every device supports `unsigned short` index. For render you must use:

```
GLushort indicies[] = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };
...
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indicies);
```